# Three.js loading object from glb file looks washed out

Tags: three.js

[image]

That's how my model is looking on https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/.

And How it's looking in my code?
[image]

I know I should share the code too and will but before that, I would like to know what might be going wrong.

1. Is this a problem with lighting?
2. Is this a problem of shadow? (I don't think so)
3. Is this related to the opacity of the object? (I don't think so because it shows opacity: 1 in code)
4. Is this related to the material of the object?

Here are some snippets of code. I'm using Angular.

HTML file:

```html
<div class="canvas-container">
  <canvas class="webgl" linear flat></canvas>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```js
    const canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = document.querySelector('canvas.webgl');
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const sizes = {
      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight
    };
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, sizes.width / sizes.height, 0.1, 100);
    camera.position.set(10, 35, 20);
    camera.layers.enableAll();
    camera.layers.toggle(1);
    this.loadTexture(scene);
    this.loadModels(scene);
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      canvas,
      antialias: true
    });
    renderer.physicallyCorrectLights = true;
    renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
    renderer.textureEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
    renderer.toneMappingExposure = 0.2;
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
    renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height);
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    const canvas_container = document.querySelector('.canvas-container');
    const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, canvas_container);
    controls.maxDistance = 50;

    const tick = () => {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(tick);
      controls.update();
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };

    tick();
```

LoadTexture Fn:

```js
  loadTexture(scene) {
    const cubeTextureLoader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader();
    const debugObject: any = {};
    const environmentMap = cubeTextureLoader.load([
      '/assets/3d.js/textures/environmentMaps/4/px.jpg',
      '/assets/3d.js/textures/environmentMaps/4/nx.jpg',
      '/assets/3d.js/textures/environmentMaps/4/py.jpg',
      '/assets/3d.js/textures/environmentMaps/4/ny.jpg',
      '/assets/3d.js/textures/environmentMaps/4/pz.jpg',
      '/assets/3d.js/textures/environmentMaps/4/nz.jpg'
    ]);
    environmentMap.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
    scene.background = environmentMap;
    scene.environment = environmentMap;
    debugObject.envMapIntensity = 0.001;
  }
```

LoadModels Fn:

```js
loadModels(scene) {
    const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();
    const updateAllMaterials = () => {
      scene.traverse(child => {
        if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh && child.material instanceof THREE.MeshStandardMaterial) {
          child.material.needsUpdate = true;
          child.castShadow = true;
          child.receiveShadow = true;
          console.log(child.material);
        }
      });
    };

    gltfLoader.load('/assets/3d.js/models/Tank.glb', gltf => {
      console.log(gltf);
      gltf.scene.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
      gltf.scene.position.set(-4, 0, 0);
      gltf.scene.rotation.y = Math.PI * 0.5;
      scene.add(gltf.scene);

      updateAllMaterials();
    });
  }
```

I've commented all other lines which I think are not necessary.

Comment: We cannot answer any of your questions without seeing your code. The problem could be any of those things, probably lights or material (#1 or #4). Your code would be the key that lets us determine which one it is. If the code is huge, make sure to narrow it down to its relevant parts. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Your code looks fine, I don't see any problem with it. Does the same thing happen if you use a [plain cylinder](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=cylin#api/en/geometries/CylinderGeometry)? It would be easier to help you if you re-created the problem with https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I've recreated the problem on stackblitz but as i can't upload glb file to stackblitz, you need to clone the project locally and i'll provide glb file if needed

Comment: Please post your model and stackblitz link. I'm willing to figure this one out.

Comment: there's a lot more support for React these days, unfortunately making this more difficult. Without stackblitz with the assets it's difficult to help.

Comment: Here is the stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-35cvms?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts and here is the glb file https://file.io/GIguyfeX9NZt